# Java: How do i put the name of a variable into a string?

Tags: java, string, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to make a mod for minecraft using Java code, and seeing as i am not asking about something directly related to minecraft i thought i would ask it here.

Inside of my code i have 
`renderItem.getItemModelMesher().register(copperIngot, 0, new ModelResourceLocation(RefStrings.MODID + ":" + ((CopperIngot) copperIngot).getName(), "inventory"));`

At the end of that line it calls for the function getName(), which is located in the file CopperIngot, and it returns the string "copperingot". what i want to do is to get the name of the variable "copperIngot" and have it set it to lowercase inside of a string called name.

My reasons for doing this is so i can have 1 file ingots, 1 file for blocks, etc. (blocks and ingots being of the variable types Block and Item which are created in the Minecraft base code)

Right now i am using the below code posted by [tinker_fairy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1891112/tinker-fairy)

```
`Field[] fields = MainRegistry.class.getDeclaredFields();
//gives no of fields
System.out.println(fields.length);         
for (Field field : fields) {
    //gives the names of the fields
    System.out.println(field.getName());   
}`
```

Which gives me a console readout like this:

> [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: instance
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: proxy
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: tabDerptech
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: scandiumIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: scandiumDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: scandiumBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: titaniumIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: titaniumDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: titaniumBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: vanadiumIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: vanadiumDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: vanadiumBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: chromiumIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: chromiumDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: chromiumBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: manganeseIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: manganeseDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: manganeseBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: ironDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: cobaltIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: cobaltDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: cobaltBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: nickelIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: nickelDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: nickelBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: copperIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: copperDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: copperBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: copperOre
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: zincIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: zincDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: zincBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: yttriumIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: yttriumDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: yttriumBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: zirconiumIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: zirconiumDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: zirconiumBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: niobiumIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: niobiumDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: niobiumBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: molybdenumIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: molybdenumDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: molybdenumBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: technetiumIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: technetiumDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: technetiumBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: rutheniumIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: rutheniumDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: rutheniumBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: rhodiumIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: rhodiumDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: rhodiumBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: palladiumIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: palladiumDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: palladiumBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: silverIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: silverDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: silverBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: cadmiumIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: cadmiumDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: cadmiumBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: hafniumIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: hafniumDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: hafniumBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: tantalumIngot
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: tantalumDust
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: tantalumBlock
>   [com.hihellobyeoh.derptech.main.MainRegistry:init:63]: tungstenIngot
>
> etc.....(i have 113 variables atm in that one file)

which is not what i want, i want it to, as it runs the getName function, to read the variable name and then write that variable name to the String name. right now with the code i have giving me all of the variables i am at a loss for how to isolate the exact variable i need to find.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you need. There is no way to find out the name of the local variable that some value is assigned to, and from your explanations I don't understand why you would need that.

Comment: What you want is not supported by java.  It is, however, supported by C#. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/849265/What-s-new-in-Csharp-nameof-Expressions

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, instead of hardcoded string, you wanted to return the name of the class in small case. 
How about using `getClass().getName().toLowerCase()` in `getName()` method of *CopperIngot.java*.

Moreover, you can very well use reflection to get the variable name and set the new value.

```
Class aClass = MyObject.class;
Field field = aClass.getField("field");
MyObject objectInstance = new MyObject();
field.set(objetInstance, value);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You just want to write it to a variable?

```
Field[] fields = MainRegistry.class.getDeclaredFields();
//gives no of fields
System.out.println(fields.length);         
for (Field field : fields) {
    //gives the names of the fields
    String name = field.getName().toLowerCase();
    if ( name.indexOf( "copper" ) > -1 ) { 
        System.out.println("you found copper: " + name);
    }   
}
```